# Why is Django redirecting my forms to a different location than the form's "action" specifies?

Tags: python, django, forms, redirect

I am making use of Django's `django.contrib.auth.forms` module, specifically the `UserCreationForm` class.

Here is the templated verion of my form, where `register_form` is the variable passed from `views.py` holding the empty `UserCreationForm`:

```
<form  id="registration" method="post" action="/register">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <table class="float_left">
        <tr><th><label for="id_username">Username:</label></th><td>{{  register_form.username }}</td></tr>
        <tr><th><label for="id_password1">Password:</label></th><td>{{  register_form.password1 }}</td></tr>
        <tr><th><label for="id_password2">Confirm Password:</label></th><td>{{  register_form.password2 }}</td></tr>
    </table>
    <input class="float_right button_input" type="submit" value="Register" />
</form>
```

It displays just fine on the page. Note that the action is set to `"/register"`. However, when I clicked on the submit button, nothing was happening. I opened up Chrome's ever-so-handy JavaScript console, and saw the following output (running on Django's `manage.py` dev server):

```
POST http://localhost:8000/includes/register.php 404 (NOT FOUND)
```

Awesome. Note that here Django (or something else, maybe) has inserted the `includes` directory into my path.

Here is the relevant snippet from `urls.py`:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^register', 'authentication.views.register'),
)
```

And `views.py`:

```
def register(request):
# csrf is used to prevent Cross-Site Request Forgeries (i.e. XSS attacks, SQL injections, etc.)
c = {}
c.update(csrf(request))

# if logged in, redirect to personal profile
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        new_user = form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect("/home")
else:
    c['register_form'] = UserCreationForm()
    return render_to_response('authentication/register.html', c, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Just a very simple redirect to `/home` if the form was valid (after saving the new user in the database) or circling back to the same page otherwise (`authentication /register.html` is the relevant template).

I am baffled.

Thanks in advance for anything you can tell me.

EDIT: I should note, I have been using `http://localhost:8000/` as the domain for the Django app I'm working on for quite a while now. In fact, this form seemed to be working fine, too, when I was using the `UserCreationForm`'s builtin `as_table()` method to print. But it looked terrible, so I switched to manually formatting the form, and now it doesn't work. I have not adjusted the `<form>` tag once. I still had to supply that before I when was auto printing.

MAJOR EDIT:

**NEVERMIND GUYS, I GOT IT.** Turns out there was some legacy code in the page that was trying to call some old php that was used for form validation before I started converting it to Django, which is what I've been doing. Thanks for the comments, but I'm gonna close this question.

Comment: I think you've missed a trailing slash. Use action="/register/"> in your form and url(r'^register/$', 'authentication.views.register') in your url.conf

Comment: Was the lack of indentation in your views.py above, just a typo when copying it into stackoverflow?

Answer (score -1):

Unless you've explicitly set it otherwise, Django's devserver serves your pages on `127.0.0.1:8000`.

From your POST URL I can only guess that you have some PHP application configured to be served on `http://localhost:8000`, probably through Apache.

Comment: No, I've been using localhost:8000 quite thoroughly to access my Django pages. Plus, I was able to get to the page where the form is displayed just fine, and that's at http://localhost:8000/. Thanks for the thought though.

Comment: @Béres, localhost **is** 127.0.0.1.